# Which SSH setting takes precedence with Git?

Tags: bash, ssh, git, key-authentication

Since I am sharing a login on a Alma Linux server with some colleagues, I was trying to better understand the precedence different settings take.
We mainly use the server to run time-consuming Python scripts, numerical methods and AI stuff.
We login via SSH from our local Windows machines.
We pull the scripts via `git` from a self-hosted Gitlab server, or upload them via `scp`.

Each one of us has his/her SSH keypair under `~/.ssh`.
(This would be the same case with *one* person having *multiple* SSH keypairs.)
Now, there are several ways to specify the key which `git` uses for `pull`/`push` via SSH.
I can specify it in

- `~/.ssh/config` as `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
- global `.gitconfig` via `git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa"`
- per repository in local `.gitconfig` via `git config core.sshCommand "ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa"`

When I use the SSH config approach with one key, say `~/.ssh/id_ed25519`, and have set the local `.gitconfig` to `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `git push` will still use the former instead of the latter.
Which shows me that the SSH config settings somehow overwrite the local `.gitconfig`, which should not be the case I find.
However, when I comment out that line in `~/.ssh/config`, it works as expected.

So my question is: Can someone explain the order in which `git` via SSH reads the settings?
Also, what happens if I change this [via an environment variable](https://ma.ttias.be/specify-a-specific-ssh-private-key-for-git-pull-git-clone/#using-a-specific-environment-variable), such as `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa' git pull`?
Will this overwrite the `~/.ssh/config`/`.gitconfig` for the specific host?

Comment: Both `IdentityFile` and `-i` are, IIRC, just suggestions to SSH and not an override. SSH will try every key it knows of including the ones mentioned in `IdentityFile` and `-i` and the ones in any agent that it can access and not just the key in `-i` or `IdentityFile`. The files you specify in `-i` or `IdentityFile` are only *appended* to the list of keys to try.

Comment: This isn't really a Git question. Git just rides on top of ssh. To understand ssh configuration, you should look in `man ssh` and `man ssh_config`.

Comment: @muru is correct that the default behavior of the OpenSSH client is to try every key it knows about and `-i` or `IdentifyFile` just add to the list of keys which will be attempted. However, this default behavior can be overridden with `IdentitiesOnly`.

Comment: Enlightening comments. I can surely do `ssh -vT gitserver` and get `Welcome to GitLab, winkmal`. But this is only server-specific, not repo-specific.
If I do `git push` with the *wrong* key, I would only find out *after* the event that I pushed under a colleagues' name, or vice versa.

*After* posting my question here, I found [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1628184/1214040), which gives a solution to my problem entirely with `~/.ssh/config`. But I would still like to understand the underlying algorithm/heuristics SSH uses to match the right key to the right user.